# customize quicktime iphone

Tags: iphone, quicktime, mpmovieplayer, customization

Did anyone tried to customize the window in which the quicktime is playing video?

If so, can you give me a hint hoe to start implementing something like this.

Thank you indeed.

**UPDATE:**  [Some apps have implemented it. See it here.](http://www.intomobile.com/2009/04/14/orange-france-launches-tv-from-orange-iphone-application-service.html)

Comment: I think i found the solution.

Comment: I am interested. What have you found ?

Comment: When i try myself, i will write here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phone doesn't have Quicktime, at least not in the traditional sense. Video playback is handled by a dedicated decoder on the system SoC. You cannot customize the movie player in any significant way, since doing so might cause it to fall off the hardware decode path, and it is entirely possible Apple doesn't even have a software decoder on the device.

So, in other words, you are limited to the options presented by [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html). If you need more customization you should file a [bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) with Apple requesting the ability and explaining why you need it, but I suspect this is a hardware limitation.

And before anyone mentions they have seen video playing non-full screen, that requires including your own software decoder for the video in your app, and while you can do that it is very complicated, and gets no hardware acceleration which means you cannot play as complicated video and it takes more power.