# iPhone SDK: Custom video player controls

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video

In my iPhone app I have designed a custom video player, currently it is very basic with just a play pause and stop button,
but I would like the user to be able to scrub, (I think thats the right word) the video like you can do with apple's original media player.
So for Instance I would like to be able to take a UISlider and have it control the current postiion of the videos playback if you get what I mean. Oh and incase your curious, the way I `pause`/`play`/`stop` the video is by using this simple piece of code `[self.theMovie play];` `[self.theMovie stop];` `[self.theMovie pause];` The trouble is I don't know how to scrub the video.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is no [self.theMovie pause]

Comment: @Cirrostratus 
It works perfectly, it does give a warning though but it still responds to it.

Comment: Interesting. Did the app get approved by Apple?

Comment: @Cirrostratus
Yes, I've had quite a few apps accepted with that code.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked the same question: [customize quicktime iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638400/customize-quicktime-iphone) and here [MPVideoPlayer add/remove buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665719/mpvideoplayer-add-remove-buttons)

It seams that you have to posibilities:

1. You can add you view over the main window. An sample can be found here: [MoviePlayer Sample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798)
2. You can iterate through views, found one you need and Add/Remove views. I don't know yet how must does Apple likes/dislikes this method.